# parallelize list of dataset spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I filter a dataset to get a list of datasets which I then want to persist in parallel.

Code:

```
val yearWiseDsList = years.map(year => ds.filter($"year".rlike(year.toString)))

yearWiseDsList.zipWithIndex.foreach {
        case (xDf, idx) =>
xDf.write.format("csv").option("header", "false").save("mydata" + "_" + (startYear + idx))
}
```

Currently the `foreach` runs sequentially. I can convert the `yearWiseDsList` to `par` `List` but then it won't be using spark for the parallelisation

How can I do this with spark?

Comment: Apache spark has a totally different parallelization scheme. You can start by searching `apache spark rdd tutorial` on Google.

Comment: Spark rdd does't help me. Either you are suggesting me to do a sc.parallelize the yearWiseDsList which I have already tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: ` it doesn't work.`... what does not work ? What is it that you could not achieve ? RDD's are the way of parallelisation in Spark. What else do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is regarding nested parallization in spark. The following link answers it.

[Nesting parallelizations in Spark? What's the right approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339300/nesting-parallelizations-in-spark-whats-the-right-approach)