# Parallelize different scenarios for pandas UDF

Tags: pyspark, parallel-processing, pandas-udf

I have created a pandas UDF (df->df) for scenario, which takes cares of parallel run for partition which can be found withing provided data - this is fine. However it was requested to have additional 20 scenarios for which a different sets of fixed parameters are used to run pUDF - I have adjusted pUDF to be flexible on these input parameters as having slightly different logic each, but I run them in series and would like to have these 20 scenarios run in parallel to shorten process time.

My question is how should I parallelize input parameters along with pUDF (aka nested parallelization)?

**Example**: Imagine I have 5 different scenarios for different ways of comparison (Mont **t**o Previous Month, Month **o**ver last year Month, Quarter...etc.) as shown in below dictionary. I need to pass dic keys into pUDF so it can process accordingly - meaning each time actual vs previous periods contain diffent set of rows for aggregation which is inside pUDF.

How would I pass this 5 dict keys (params) into pUDF for one paralleled run instead of having a loop over them?

```
dic_param_compmethod = {
    "MtM": {'prv_end':-1   , 'mon_range' : None  },
    "MoM": {'prv_end':-12  , 'mon_range' : 0     },
    "QtQ": {'prv_end':-3   , 'mon_range' : -2    },
    "QoQ": {'prv_end':-12  , 'mon_range' : -2    },
    "YoY": {'prv_end':-12  , 'mon_range' : None  }
}
```

Based on what I found so far, I'm not sure what's the appropriate way of getting across this as I believe similar scenario must be a daily bread for many - if not this way, how this should be accomplished ? I can only think of running different jobs each with own cluster.

Many thanks for any guidance on this!

**So far found:** I thought SparkContext.parallelize() could help me but then also information that it is not able to handle nested parallelized function ([Nesting parallelizations in Spark? What's the right approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339300/nesting-parallelizations-in-spark-whats-the-right-approach) ).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example : The answers provided here should help you out.

Comment: @user238607 - sorry, not sure what in particular you mean. Basically Im already applying pandas UDF using applyInPandas as the last answer in that thread. My question would be how to run in parallel the last line for various scenarios - from that example it is this line: df.groupby('id').applyInPandas(mean_func, schema="id long, v double") - for this line, let's assume I have 10 different aggregates next to 'id' column - how would I do that? Can you please point me to any particular direction? Thank you

Comment: If you have 10 scenarios which are represented by input parameters to the pandas udf, then you will groupby those scenario parameters and use them inside the pandas udf. By this you will achieve only 10 independent executions assuming your pandas udf depends on the whole input dataframe in a sequential manner i.e. they can't be parallelized further.

Comment: @user238607 - ah ok, so you're telling me that I could achieve this by using e.g. parallelize() within pandas UDF to process some parameter's in parallel runs - thus pandas UDF would be split to worker nodes as well eventual nested parallelization?? - isn't this actually a limitation I described above as parallelization wound not really reach the worker nodes? Besides, I have also parameters which define what fields enters the groupby part while applying pandas over pyspark df - for this I couldn't apply your proposal though. At the end I'm not sure if pandas UDF is a suitable solution overall